# Explanation of different testtype and teststats in ctree in party package of R

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart

I was looking into the `ctree` function in the `party` package for R. In the `ctree_control` parameters I found the following options for `teststat` and `testtype`:

```
teststat = c("quad", "max")
testtype = c("Bonferroni", "Univariate", "Teststatistic")
```

Could someone please help me understand the details of each `testtype` and `teststat`, and when one should use each option. The documentation of the `party` package did not cover these in detail.

Answer (score 5):

By default, `ctree` assesses the null hypothesis of no association between the response and all regressor variables using a quadratic correlation test statistic. Depending on whether the involved variables are numeric, categorical, or survival, different types of scores are used in these correlation tests. See also: [What is the test statistics used for a conditional inference regression tree?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144143/what-is-the-test-statistics-used-for-a-conditional-inference-regression-tree)

Alternatively, a maximally-selected statistic can be used which makes a difference if one of the score functions used are multivariate (e.g., for multi-level categorical variables).

And, by default, the resulting p-values are Bonferroni-corrected for multiple testing across the number of regressor variables. Alternatively, the Bonferroni correction can be omitted (`"Univariate"`) or the test statistics themselves rather than their p-values can be used (`"Teststatistic"`).

In most situations there should be no need to modify the defaults. For more details about the `ctree` algorithm see:

- `vignette("ctree", package = "partykit")` as well as the original manuscript: Torsten Hothorn, Kurt Hornik, Achim Zeileis (2006). Unbiased Recursive Partitioning: A Conditional Inference Framework. *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, **15**(3), 651–674. [doi:10.1198/106186006X133933](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/106186006X133933)

For the underlying conditional inference techniques:

- `vignette("LegoCondInf", package = "coin")` as well as the original manuscript: Torsten Hothorn, Kurt Hornik, Mark A. Van de Wiel, Achim Zeileis (2006). A Lego System for Conditional Inference. *The American Statistician*, **60**(3), 257–263. [doi:10.1198/000313006X118430](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/000313006X118430)