# Influence function used in partykit for binary classification

Tags: r, classification, cart, party, influence-function

What is the influence function used for binary classification in the R package `partkit`, specifically for the conditional tree (`ctree`). I could not find any details in the R package documentation. In the vigente I found this paragraph about classification:

[image]

But the function $e_J(Y_i)$ is not defined. What is $e_J(Y_i)$? and is it the influence function used for the function `ctree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is defined at the top of page 10 in `vignette("ctree", package = "partykit")`, albeit briefly: $e_K(k)$ is the unit vector of length $K$ with $k$-th element being equal to one.

As an example, if you do classification with $J = 4$ classes and the second class is observed in observation $i$ with $Y_i = 2$, then $e_J(Y_i) = (0, 1, 0, 0)^\top$.

See also the following for more explanations: [What is the test statistics used for a conditional inference regression tree?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144143/what-is-the-test-statistics-used-for-a-conditional-inference-regression-tree)